# DENSE RANK in both ways

Tags: sql, oracle

Thanks to answers to my previous question, I could establish this kind of query

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e6f9/7/0

The result table shows work time right before each pause data.

From this, I would like to add another column which shows "work time right after each pause data", resulting as below.

```
STAFF | MAX(...) | START_TIME | END_TIME | MIN(...)
------+----------+------------+----------+---------
GC01  | 12:00    | 12:03      | 12:07    | 12:10  
GC01  | 12:20    | 12:25      | 12:35    | 12:40  
GC02  | 12:33    | 12:35      | 12:45    | (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.  You need to rejoin to the work table:

```
select p.staff, 
   max(w.work_time) keep (dense_rank first order by w.work_time desc),
   p.start_time, p.end_time,
   min(w2.work_time) keep (dense_rank first order by w2.work_time)
from pause p
   join work w
      on p.staff = w.staff
         and p.start_time >= w.work_time
left join work w2
   on p.staff = w2.staff
      and p.end_time <= w2.work_time
group by p.staff, p.start_time, p.end_time
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e6f9/14)